# Cocos2d: Black Screen after loading scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game where I need to reload scenes many times.
What I decided to do is when I finish each level to clear my current scene, create another "buffer" scene and then reload the first one (after having cleared my memory).

The problem is that after I get from the buffer scene to the last one, a black screen appears. In the console I can see that the last scene was loaded and initiated correctly but still nothing appears..

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: have your previous scene dealloc??

Comment: cocos2d-iphone / cocos2d-android / cocos2d-x ? and version ?